# Why can't I embed lua in an x64 project?

Tags: c++, lua, architecture, linker-errors

I'm making a project using OpenCV and Lua in C++. OpenCV requires x64 and when I embedded lua it started giving me linker errors(like : **Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol lua_tostring referenced in function "blah blah"**). When I switch back to x86 OpenCV starts complaining and I don't get any errors related to the linker or lua. I really want to use both of them in one project, any solution?

**Note**: I've embedded lua in many other projects and I didn't have any problems with linker errors , I'm pretty sure I did everything right.

Comment: Please provide information on: your toolchain, platform, build scripts/process. Just writing it doesn't work and it should, doesn't really help.

Answer (score 2):

The lua headers do not check for c++ translation units.

Add extern "C" { } around your lua includes:

```
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
}
```

Or uuse lua.hpp instead of lua.h.

Comment: I'm aware of that, tried that too before asking this question, still the same error... It's all about the architecture, I guess.